# I can't install ar_track_alvar on ROS Noetic

Tags: ros

I download ROS Noetic but when I paste this line on Terminal, it can't found.

`$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ar-track-alvar`

How can I solve this problem?

As I know, this package is avaliable for Noetic but I can't install it.

Answer (score 2):

That command is trying to install the package for Indigo, not Noetic. Make sure your package names include the ROS distro you’re targeting.

```
sudo apt install ros-noetic-ar-track-alvar
```

**Edit based on comment**: It does appear there is a noetic build for this package, but it doesn't look like it's officially tracked on the ROS wiki. If it isn't supplied via apt you will need to build the package from source. The Noetic source can be found [here on GitHub](https://github.com/ros-perception/ar_track_alvar/tree/noetic-devel).

Comment: I have also tried this command but It didn't work too, I think ar_track_alvar doesn't exist on Noetic interestingly because I search all packages on that after asking this question, but I can't find it.

Comment: @Tuğrul765 I've updated my answer to address what you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

I happened to do this *just now* so here's what worked for me:

- Run `git clone https://github.com/machinekoder/ar_track_alvar.git -b noetic-devel` in your workspace (`~/catkin_ws` in my case)
- Install a bunch of needed dependencies `sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-cv-bridge ros-noetic-image-transport ros-noetic-pcl-conversions ros-noetic-pcl-ros ros-noetic-resource-retriever libtinyxml-dev -y`

If the second one does not work for you, you might need to also run the following

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu `lsb_release -cs` main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80' --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654
sudo apt-get update
```

Finally run a `catkin_build` in your workspace and don't forget to source `~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` (or whatever your workspace is named)